# Passing dynamic object prop with router link to nested tab Ionic Vue

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework

I am trying to pass a movie data object through `router-link` to a nested tab `MoviePage.vue` with Ionic and VueJS. Upon retrieving the movie data object as a `prop`, I would then like to display some of its properties on the `MoviePage` tab.
I've went through several methods such as passing the props as the param and the Provide/Inject method but not of them are working. Am I overcomplicating things or is there a more straight forward way to my problem?

Here is what I have so far:

`Tab2Page.vue`

```
<template>
    ...
        <ion-content :fullscreen="true">
            <p v-if="!movieData">Loading...</p>
            <pre v-else>
        <ion-grid>
                <ion-row>
                    <ion-col size="6" :key="movie.Id" v-for="movie in movieData.Data.Movies">
            ...
            <ion-img :src="movie.LargePosterUrl"></ion-img>
            <ion-button :router-link="`/tab2/movie/${movie.Id}`" router-direction="forward">More info</ion-button>
                    </ion-col>
                </ion-row>
            </ion-grid>
      </pre>
        </ion-content>
    ...
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
...
import { ref, provide } from 'vue';

const movieData = ref(null);

const fetchData = async () => {
    movieData.value = null;
    try {
        const res = await fetch('https://www.eventcinemas.com.au/Movies/GetNowShowing');
        if (!res.ok) {
            throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${res.status}`);
        }
        movieData.value = await res.json();
        provide('someMovieData', movieData.value);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
};

fetchData();
</script>
```

`routes -> index.ts`

```
...
const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
    ...
    {
        path: '/tabs/',
        component: TabsPage,
        children: [
            ...
            {
                path: '/tab2/movie/:movieId',
                name: 'movieInfo',
                component: () => import('@/views/MoviePage.vue'),
                props: true
            }
        ]
    }
];

...
```

`MoviePage.vue`

```
<template>
    <ion-page>
        ...
        <ion-content :fullscreen="true">
            <!-- Full movie details such as: Name, image, release date, genre, director, etc. -->
            <p>{{ someMovieData }}</p>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-page>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
...
import { defineProps, inject } from 'vue';

const someMovieData = inject('someMovieData');
...
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use `provide` inside a function instead of a component, it won't work as expected because provide should be called within the context of a Vue component instance.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, provide } from 'vue';

const movieData = ref(null);

// move provide here
provide('movieData', movieData);

const fetchData = async () => {
    movieData.value = null;
    try {
        const res = await fetch('https://www.eventcinemas.com.au/Movies/GetNowShowing');
        if (!res.ok) {
            throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${res.status}`);
        }
        movieData.value = await res.json();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
};

fetchData();
</script>
```

Also another suggestion to consider is using state management, such as [Pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/), for shared state. This would allow you to access and pass data around more easily. Instead of passing the entire movie object as a route parameter, you could just pass the movie ID. Then, in the component responsible for displaying the movies, you can retrieve the movie data using the provided ID.

If using Pinia seems like overkill for your scenario, you could consider passing the movie data values as query parameters. However, keep in mind that passing large amounts of data via query parameters may not be the most efficient approach (anti-pattern).